# Add custom link/pop up under variations dropdown

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Im looking for a simple code to show a "Size guide"-link below the Size dropdown. Is there a easy way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try the action `woocommerce_before_single_variation`

```
add_action("woocommerce_before_single_variation", function () {

    // the product is in the variable $GLOBALS["product"]

    ?>

        <strong>
            <?php echo $GLOBALS["product"]->get_name();?>
        </strong>

    <?php


});
```

Comment: This function won't work for me. Sure, the text displays, but above the add to cart and not below the second variation dropdown shown in the pic. Any idea how to fix it?